# Track a user and disallow multiple windows/tabs with php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to set up a system that allows a visitor to view only one webpage at a time.
Only one browser window or tab should be allowed.

I have implemented a session variable called "is_viewing". If it is true, the person is denied access to the pages (by simply showing a different template).

What is the best way to reset this session variable if a user navigates from one page to another?

I have added a ajax function to the html body's onunload event. All it does is set the session variable to false.

But this brings all kinds of trouble and unexpected results.
Refreshing the page first shows the deny template (with the session variable being shown as true for some reason that I do not know) and then after another refresh I can load the page again.

Can't I work with headers on a script that is called with ajax?
How else would I reset the session variable and track where the user is going on the site to deny him access if he is already viewing another page?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the user really wants to view multiple windows or tabs, they can just disable Javascript.

Comment: I have several pages with live video feeds. I need to prevent people from viewing multiple of those pages at once. If you turn off javascript, then you will not see the video. So the site is only usable with javascript and I don't have to worry about those people who have javascript turned off.

Comment: Either only allow them one stream per ip, or set a cookie you check when streaming, only allow one stream per cookie id.

Comment: Well, that's what I am trying to do (with server-sided sessions). The problem is how I can reliably delete that cookie when the visitor opens a new tab or navigates to a different stream?

Comment: @user478419: look at my post: "kill old connections when new ones come in"

Comment: Hope you are realizing what it will be either too easy to bypass, or very unfriendly toward users.

Comment: @user205376: Hope you are realizing that restricting how users may use information you serve is unfriendly. I think that there is not safe AND user-friendly way of doing it.

Comment: @thejh, what you are proposing is restriction in _serving_. In particular, it will break first user experience when Nth user come. So nobody will be happy with killing stream scheme.

Comment: @user205376: There's no secure alternative to doing it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stop people from doing that, limit the number of connections per IP on the server. But please don't limit it to one or so to avoid locking a whole family or so when they have multiple PCs.

If it's ok when people willingly ignore that limit (for example by launching another browser), give each user a cookie and limit the number of connections per cookie on the server - kill old connections when new ones come in.